# How to have nexus download the newest package from npmjs official site when package is not present in local

Tags: npm, nexus

I have updated the npmjs package to 0.1.148, but when I update the package in macOS using this pnpm command:

```
> pnpm update --force
 WARN  using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing
 ERR_PNPM_NO_MATCHING_VERSION  No matching version found for rd-component@^0.1.148

This error happened while installing a direct dependency of red dwarf/frontend/texhub-web

The latest release of rd-component is "0.1.147".

If you need the full list of all 144 published versions run "$ pnpm view rd-component versions".
Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
```

I am using the nexus `OSS 3.51.0-01` proxy to forward the npm package.

How do I fetch the package from the official npmjs website when the package did not exists in local machine?
this is the proxy configuration:

[image]

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in this post https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/g/nexus-users/c/JmrhDLKcMA8/m/IdMkoXAqCQAJ it might be a Nexus cache configuration problem: by default Nexus caches the presence (and/or absence) of a package for 24 hours (1440 minutes).

Check these settings:

- **Maximum component age**: set it to `-1`

  - [Nexus npm repo - cache settings - Maximum component age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQapR.png)
- **Negative Cache** -> disable **Not found cache enabled** flag

  - [Nexus npm repo - cache settings - Negative Cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB234.png)